# How the include paths should be provided to cdt plugin

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse plugin which automates the loading of the `C projects` into `Eclipse for C/C++ development`.
One of the automation steps we are doing is to add programatically all the paths from the project structure to the `CDT` include paths in this manner `CDT` can find the included files.

The result is that we end up with a f(l)at `Includes` entry in `Project Explorer` which for projects with complex/deep level structure ends up in non-responding eclipse when trying to expand it(by mistake) or to navigate(by curiosity) through it.

I am also thinking that perhaps it is also slowing down CDT if it searches for a header file through the list of `Includes` and the file is in the last folder from the list.

Therefore, I was questioning if this is bad practice and we are not aware of the regular workflow or this is the normal way of doing it.

---

Comment: How many include paths do you have in your project?

Comment: @HighCommander4 It varies, but as a reference, there are projects which start from 100 includes to 3-4k

Comment: I can understand expanding a tree node with 4000 children in the Project Explorer taking a lot of time (because UI elements have to be created / drawn for each child). However, I wouldn't expect this to be a problem for internal uses of the include list such as resolving headers.

Comment: @HighCommander4 I understand, so this is the normal behaviour, the CDT doesn't resolve itself the paths of the current open project, I have to provide them to it.